# Python - Send item to next page in Word

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word

I am trying to send text to the next page in a .docx file using Python. So far, I have written a some code that will locate a certain word in a .docx file (using python-docx):

```
from docx import *    
document = Document('temp.docx')
    
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if 'Hello' in paragraph.text:
        print (paragraph.text)
```

Now I want to send each occurrence of "Hello" to a new page so that each page in my Word document starts with the word "Hello".

> **Current Doc:** Hello blahblahblahbalh Hello sampletextsampletext
>
> **Output:**
>
> Hello blahblahblah
>
> *New Page*
>
> Hello sampletextsampletext

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.add_page_break ?

Comment: @fredtantini The word I'm looking for might be in the middle of the docx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not look very pretty (or professional) but it gets the job done:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_BREAK
import re

doc = Document('temp.docx')
new_doc = Document()
word = 'Hello'

'''Get the whole document text from all paragraphs'''
whole_text=''
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    if whole_text!='':
        whole_text+='\n'
    whole_text += p.text

'''To split whole_text but include Hello in the created list
put parentheses around the word and use re.split'''
split_p = re.split(word.join('()'),whole_text)

'''Now if 'Hello' was the first word of whole_text re.split will create
['','Hello','...']
if that's the case, remove first '' to avoid unwanted page_break at the
start'''
if split_p[0]=='':
    split_p.remove('')

i = 0
while i<len(split_p):
    if split_p[i] == word:
        '''We don't want to add break at the start of document'''
        if len(new_doc.paragraphs)>0:
            '''new_doc.add_page_break() creates a newline with page break on it
            but the below command will put page break on the last paragraph
            so there won't be additional empty lines

            If you don't want to have an additional import line
            then just put 7 instead of WD_BREAK.PAGE'''
            new_doc.paragraphs[-1].add_run().add_break(WD_BREAK.PAGE)
        '''Add 'Hello' + the text coming after it'''
        new_doc.add_paragraph(split_p[i]+split_p[i+1])
        i+=2
    else:
        '''If the first Hello is not at the start of document just add the
        text'''
        new_doc.add_paragraph(split_p[i])
        i+=1

new_doc.save('hello.docx')
```

Comment: It works perfectly. And thanks for taking the time to explain it.